# get count of json element(s) in php

Tags: php, json, element

My json is this :

```
{
"id1527":{"stats":"true"},
"id6376373":{"stats":"true"},
"id63737":{"stats":"true"}
}
```

how can get count of all ids(like 'id1527' or 'id6376373'...)

Comment: Are all of the top-level properties going to be IDs, or do they need validating?

Answer (score 2):

After parsing the JSON, `array_filter()` to filter this just to the ones with a key that begins with `id`, and `count()` to count them:

```
count(array_filter(json_decode($json, true), function($key) {
    return substr($key, 0, 2) == "id";
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you mean this.

```
$str = '{"id1527":{"stats":"true"},"id6376373":{"stats":"true"},"id63737":"stats":"true"},"x444":{"stats":"false"}}';

echo count(preg_grep("/^id(\d)+$/",array_keys(json_decode($str,true))));
```

This code snippet checks to see whether the top-level key of the JSON array has a preceding text "id" and take only those records into account.

Comment: Maybe add some description.

Comment: Well. The code checks to see whether the top-level key of the JSON array has a preceding text "id" and take only those records into account. Should I change my answer too? I am new here

Comment: I know what it does but the questioner probably doesn't. Best to add to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Decode to an array and count the elements.

```
count(json_decode($json, true));
```

Comment: I need just ids elements count. not all elements

Comment: Based on the info you provided, this is the count of the ids.  The ids are the only keys in the first level of the JSON object.